# Integrating a Backbone app with Parse.com and Meteor

Tags: backbone.js, meteor, parse-platform

I have a Backbone app running on Parse.com and i would like to integrate it into Meteor. The main reason i'm doing this is because with the Parse.com javascript SDK your keys are exposed and i'm trying to hide them and just render the content directly. Is this even possible? Can the javascript SDK run on the server?

I just started with Meteor and it looks promising but i'm having a hard time understanding the dynamics of how it works and if it would be possible to integrate it into a database hosted in Parse.com which has it's own custom objects and methods.

In this case for example:

```
Step = new Meteor.Collection("step");
```

This data is served from the mongoDB in meteor, would it be possible to serve it from Parse.com?

Summing up:

1. Is it possible to run the Parse.com javascript SDK on the server and have access to their objects?
2. if question1 == true, how can I replace the content being served to the Meteor.Collections from the MongoDB to my Parse objects.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parse's JavaScript SDK Keys will follow any ACLs set on your objects. Even if someone copies your keys, they'd need to also login with one of your user's username and passwords successfully in order to read/write objects that are protected by ACLs.

Comment: @HectorRamos I see... The thing is, i have objects and/or fields like `Favorites` or `numberOfFollowers` that have `{"*":{"write":true,"read":true}}` since it's shown to unregistered users. How would I go about that?

Comment: You can have read-only global ACLs such as {"*": { "read": true }}, and only allow registered, signed in users to "write" to objects they own.